# How effective is constant folding in a C compiler?

Tags: c, compilation, constantfolding

My question may be too easy, but I have not found the answer, sorry for that.

if I have some code like this:

```
...
#define N 6
...
float a, b;
...
a = 2.0 * 3 * N * b;
...
```

then, after compilation, will this code become something like this?

```
...
a = 36.0 * b;
...
```

In other words, the constant part will be calculated at compile time, right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Avoid result dependence on operator precedence rules by putting macro definition in parentheses i.e. `#define N 6-1` is not the same as `#define N (6-1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, but not guaranteed.

You can try and look at the disassembly of your program (either in a debugger, or in a disassembler or use a compiler switch (if available) to produce assembly code from your C code).

Comment: + increasing of optimization level does not decrease the probability of constant folding ;)

Comment: thank you very much, what should i do if i want to save run time?

Comment: Use appropriate (to your problem) algorithms and data structures. Enable compiler optimizations (if not enabled). That's the general answer to the general question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define val 10

int main()
{

int b = 100;
int k = (5 * val) + b;
//int k = (5 * 25) + b; 

return 0;
}
```

val is replaced 10 during pre-processing,

`cpp ss.c` gives me

```
int main()
{    
         int b = 100;
         int k = (5 * 10) + b;    
         return 0;
}
```

If we look at assembly(gcc -S ss.c),

```
 .file   "ss.c"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    $100, -8(%rbp)
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
        addl    $50, %eax            //5 * 10 calculated !!!
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

so constants are calculated at compile time itself in gcc.